# Webpack - extract-text-webpack-plugin Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass, webpack

**webpack.config.js**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

I immediately receive this error if I just implement the plugin:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/ConcatSource'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lucamormile/Documents/Lavori/Webapps/React/webpack_test/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/index.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

What did i forgot?

Comment: npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: It's already installed...

Comment: This [bug on the github repo](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/133) seems relevant.

Comment: News from the future which might be worth considering: `npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Please use ` https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin.

Answer (score 20):

Do you have `webpack` module on your project?
If not, install it locally (not globally):

```
$ npm install webpack [--save-dev]
```

`extract-text-webpack-plugin` needs `webpack` as peer dependency, but npm 3 doesn't install peer dependencies automatically.

Comment: For me this worked for yarn by yarn add extract-text-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 18):

You can try this command which I found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve it by use

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$ npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next` and this would solve your issue

Let me know if this worked.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6568

Comment: This worked for me. I also tried the other fixes before I tried this. For some reason, the others didn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Running `npm i node-sass` might solve your problem

Comment: It is helpful to briefly describe why that would work. Future readers will be more likely to try it.